# HttpWebRequest .Net Core set Timeout

Tags: c#, .net-core, system.net

I am trying to set the Timeout on an HttpWebRequest and it seems that it is not possible in .Net Core. The property 'Timeout' is no longer there.

Thanks

Comment: Which version of .NET Core are you using?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I am trying to set the Timeout on an HttpWebRequest and it seems that it is not possible in .Net Core.

It is possible in .NET Core if you are using .NET Core 2.0. You can see [the support for the `Timeout` property here](https://apisof.net/catalog/System.Net.HttpWebRequest.Timeout).

[image]

If you can, use the [System.Net.Http.HttpClient](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpclient(v=vs.118).aspx) instead, [because...](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/7862)

> In general, for better app performance and features, we recommend developers move away from HttpWebRequest and adopt HttpClient API surface.